# How to position Label from right to left instead of left to right according to language selected?

Tags: android, locale

I have a multi language application. which works fine for the app is in the English language and all labels are placed perfectly at the required places.

Now I have a scenario  when I change the language of the from English to Arabic app is doing the translation correctly. But issue is with the placement of the labels, I want to place the labels from rtl instead of ltr.

Comment: All the answers: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html#SupportLayoutMirroring

Answer (score 3):

**For API level 17 or higher** Set the property `textDirection` in your XML

```
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

**For below API level 17** use property `textAlignment` in your XML

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Comment: Welcome. :) @KamranSohail

Answer (score 1):

In order to support RTL in your app, you first need to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `<application>` element in your manifest file.

If your app API ≥ 17, replace all

`layout_marginLeft` with `layout_marginStart`

`layout_marginRight` with `layout_marginEnd`

`paddingLeft` with `paddingStart`

`paddingRight` with `paddingEnd`

and if your app support API<17 add `layout_marginStart`, `layout_marginEnd` along with `layout_marginLeft`, `layout_marginRight`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ankita's answer you can use `textDirection:"anyRtl"`, which will set the direction of the text to the right if it finds any strong "right direction" character or to the left he it finds a strong "left direction" character

From [Documentation of views](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL)

> Text direction is using "any-RTL" algorithm. The paragraph direction is RTL if it contains any strong RTL character, otherwise it is LTR if it contains any strong LTR characters. If there are neither, the paragraph direction is the view's resolved layout direction.

I would recommend making 2 different layouts for each view one with left direction and one with right direction. In that case you will have the liberty to adapt your layout to the type of text you're going to have and so use `textDirection="rtl"`

Either cases are good, the first one from Ankita is  useful when you don't need full control of the display and you can  permit yourself to trust the "anyRTL" algorythm.

The second solution, gives you more work but will give you full control over the result layout.

One last thing. I'm not sure but by creating a layout with the arabic locale I think the text direction changes automatically

[image: Right ot Left or Left to right layout]